# How do I Call the function via the pointer? (Assembly)

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I've loaded the register rcx with a pointer to a function. How do I call the function via the pointer as a one liner with no "extern". I'm very new to this so please go easy on me.

This is what I've tried:

```
mov rax, QWORD[rcx]
ret
```

Comment: You need a `call` instruction: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call

Comment: You could write a C program that does it and then look at the assembly. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rzxsE9sTj)

Comment: goldbolt.org has many compilers you can access online to try yourself.

Comment: `call rcx` should suffice... of course, details are missing in your question and things may change. If you need help with a specific program make sure to include a [mre] and describe the problem as detailed as possible.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: `jmp rcx` to tailcall, otherwise for a Windows x64 function that takes an arg and calls a pointed-to function, you'd need to reserve shadow space and align the stack with `sub rsp, 40` / `call rcx` / `add rsp, 40` / `ret`.  If you just did `call rcx`, you couldn't safely `ret` because your own return address would have been part of the shadow space of your callee.